# store only time in HH24:MM format in a table? is it possible?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to know if I can store a field called `flight_time` this is the time the flight departs not how long it takes like someone else suggested making me use the wrong data type of interval....

I want to just store a time and not the current time but one in the future I have the date written out in a separate field `flight_date`.

**Questions**

Maybe I am approaching this wrong as I think you can store the time with the date in that one field?

Is there any data type where I can mask the format but I don't want to convert anything?

What about just using `VARCHAR2` because I am going to type it out any way once I populate the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store flight date and time value as a single column of type date. You can then choose how to format that value for your UI.

If you use 11g you could pre-format it using virtual columns e.g:

```
create table t1
   ( flight_date date,
     flight_time as (to_char(flight_date,'HH24:SS:MI')),
     flight_day as (to_char(flight_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'))
   );
```

although formatting should probably be done in your UI code.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not have the concept of a time of day data type. There's `DATE`, which includes both the date and time of day. There's `TIMESTAMP`, which includes fractional seconds.

Datetime calculations in Oracle are done using units of one day. So, `SYSDATE+1` is this time tomorrow. `SYSDATE+0.25` is 6 hours from now. If you ever want to use this time that you're storing to determine a `DATE` type value, you should store it as a `NUMBER`. If all you want is to store a string that looks like a time, you can use `VARCHAR2`, but you would also be able to store nonsensical values like 66:74.

Comment: Storing the number of minutes past midnight is the best approach.  You can put a check constraint on to ensure the value is within range.  Conversion to a display-friendly format is a UI layer issue.

Comment: I don't see why storing that is "better". It's still floating point math (?) to add it to any datetime data type, with an additional conversion necessary to get it in the units that Oracle expects. Why minutes and not seconds or hours?

Comment: Storing it as hours or seconds or milliseconds past midnight would be just as good as minutes.  Storing it as a string is worse because the optimizer expects continuous ranges, arithmetic is harder and a tight check constraint it harder to write.

Answer (score 1):

There is [INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i78291) that, with a check constraint to accept only values with 0 seconds, could suite for your needs:

```
SQL> create table flight (
  2     time interval day(0) to second (0),
  3     constraint chk_time
  4     check(
  5             extract(second from time) = 0
  6         )
  7  )
  8  /

Table created
SQL> insert into flight(time)
  2  values (interval '10:30' hour to minute)
  3  /

1 row inserted
SQL> insert into flight(time)
  2  values (interval '10:30:30' hour to second)
  3  /

insert into flight(time)
values (interval '10:30:30' hour to second)

ORA-02290: check constraint (ESTCEDAR.CHK_TIME) violated
SQL> insert into flight(time)
  2  values (interval '23:30' hour to minute)
  3  /

1 row inserted
SQL> insert into flight(time)
  2  values (interval '24:30' hour to minute)
  3  /

insert into flight(time)
values (interval '24:30' hour to minute)

ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
SQL> insert into flight(time)
  2  values (interval '1 10:30:30' day to second)
  3  /

insert into flight(time)
values (interval '1 10:30:30' day to second)

ORA-01873: the leading precision of the interval is too small
SQL> select *
  2  from flight
  3  /

TIME
-------------------
+0 10:30:00
+0 23:30:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's notion of time within a day is fraction-of-a-day.

Accordingly, you could store time as a floating point number between zero and one, or as an integer number of minutes between 0 and 1439, for example.

In the first case, you could display it like this:

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+FRACTIME, 'HH24:MI:SS')

In the second case you could display it like this:

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+(MINUTES/1440), 'HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: why are you including SYSDATE? I want to define the datatype during the CREATE TABLE statement is what you suggested going to work. When I go to my INSERT INTO statement will I just type VALUES('19:00')

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd go for a custom *Object Type* but that's because I've been brought up with OO. It will give you plenty of benefits if you approach it well.